# How to add text to image with FFmpeg and export image?

Tags: image, text

How to add text to image with FFmpeg and export image?

[image]

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

you can add text with extra layer of div over image

look example:

```css
div{
  position:absolute;
  top:120px;
  left:80px;
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg" width="50%"/>
<div>Hello World</div>
```